# Induce Lie algebra isomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

In the picture below, how to show the Lemma 2.2.6 ?  According to 2.2.9, I can deal RHS of 2.2.12, but LHS of 2.2.12  I don't know how to deal.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $$\psi(p)=p',\ \psi(U)=U'$$ $$(\psi_\ast X) f (p')
=df\ \psi_\ast X_p =d(f\circ \psi)\ X_p\ \ast$$

Define $$ F_{X,f} : U'\subset N\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\
F_{X,f}(p'):=(\psi_\ast X) f (p') $$

and $$ G_{X,f} : U\subset M\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\
G_{X,f}(p)=d(f\circ \psi)\ X_p
$$

Note that $\ast$ implies that $$ F_{X,f}\circ \psi =G_{X,f} $$

(2) Note that $F_{X,f}$ is a function on $U'$ Hence $$
F_{Y,F_{X,f}} \circ \psi =G_{Y,F_{X,f}}
$$

Here $$ F_{Y,F_{X,f}}=\psi_\ast Y\ F_{X,f} (p')= \psi_\ast Y\ \bigg(
\psi_\ast X f\bigg) (p') $$

and \begin{align*}
 G_{Y,F_{X,f}}&=d(F_{X,f}\circ \psi)\ Y_p\\&=
dG_{X,f}\ Y_p\\&= \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\bigg|_{t=0}
G_{X,f}(C_Y(t,p))
\\&= \frac{\partial }{\partial t} d(f\circ \psi)\ X_{C_Y(t,p)}\\&=
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\bigg|_{s=0}
  (f\circ \psi )\circ C_X(s,C_Y(t,p) )
\end{align*}

where $C_W$ is flow of vector field $W$ on $M$ So we complete the proof by (3)

(3) If $h$ is a function on $M$ then \begin{align*} Xh(p)&=\frac{\partial
}{\partial t} h\circ C_X(t,p) \\&\\ YXh&=Y_p (Xh)\\&=
\frac{\partial }{\partial t} (Xh)\circ C_Y(t,p)\\&= \frac{\partial
}{\partial t} (Xh)
 \bigg(C_Y(t,p) \bigg)\\&=
 \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial s}
 h\circ C_X (s, C_Y(t,p) ) \bigg) \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks very much. Inspired by your answer, I calculate it again. Maybe, it will be distinct by respecting vector field as class of curves as your way . But I still fail to know how to get  Lemma 2.2.6 directly from Lemma 2.2.3 . Do you know how to do it ?